Controlling a shape key with multiple custom properties
A model I'm working with has multiple shape keys that change the shape of the body. What I'm trying to do is set up a custom property to make a "preset" for some of these shape keys. (i.e. the property, when turned on, will set 1 shape key to a given value and another to a given value). However, I still want to be able to edit the shape keys individually even with the presets. Is there a way to achieve this in Blender?
